# Test file image size validation with rspec without using a large file in fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I'm using paperclip in rails 3 and I want to ensure that my application doesn't allow the user to upload large images.

I can test for the file's existence and mime type of an image using a fixture like so:

```
it "is not valid without an image" do
  @post.image = nil
  @post.should_not be_valid
end

it "is not valid with the wrong file extension" do
  @post.image = File.new(Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/images/rails.bmp')
  @post.should_not be_valid
end
```

These tests work just fine. But I don't want to use a large binary file in my fixture for testing. I don't want to have a 6Mb file in my code base for testing purposes.

How can I mock up the image somehow or create an image file during the test rather than use a fixture? Should I bother testing this at all?

Many thanks...

Comment: I have this same question. Did you ever figure out a way?

Comment: Sorry it was too long ago. :) Is the answer below helpful?

Comment: I ended up rolling my own by creating temp files before the tests and deleting them after. I just copy a small file used for other validations and truncate at the desired length.

Answer (score -1):

You can use imagemagick if you have it installed

```
`convert -size 1x1 xc:white empty.jpg`
```

will create a 1x1 blank jpeg.